# Should an npm eslint-config package place the config package it extends within devDependencies?

Tags: dependency-management, eslint, package.json

I am publishing a sharable eslint-config on npm. My configuration extends `eslint-config-airbnb`. Should I install `eslint-config-airbnb` as a devDependency?

When I `npm i --save-dev eslint-config-myconfig` in another project will the `eslint-config-myconfig` dependencies be bundled in production builds?

```
//index.js
module.exports = {
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {... my overrides}
}

//package.json
...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "eslint": ">= 4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1"
  }
```

https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/shareable-configs#creating-a-shareable-config

Answer (score 1):

I was just wondering the same thing and the link you provided actually explains all that:

> If your shareable config depends on a plugin, you should also specify it as a peerDependency (plugins will be loaded relative to the end user’s project, so the end user is required to install the plugins they need). However, if your shareable config depends on a third-party parser or another shareable config, you can specify these packages as dependencies.

So

- eslint itself and plugins → peerDependency
- parsers and configs → dependency

In your case the three plugins must be moved into the peer dependencies.